# mutate_at and if_else with multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I'm trying to replace NA values from value to the value_max, where value and value_max are hundreds of columns with naming pattern as mentioned above. You can recreate, if you run everything except last line. So, the last line was my thoughts on how it should be done, but there are some errors. I can do it for separate columns easily, but how can I scale it to hundreds of columns?

```r
group1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
group2 = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
group3 = c(NA,0,1,NA,0,1,NA,0,1,NA,0,1,NA,0,1,NA,0,1)
value1 = c(100,NA,NA,500,600,400,NA,NA,100,150,NA,NA,600,700,500,NA,NA,200)
value2 = c(100,200,150,200,300,500,NA,NA,NA,200,400,300,400,600,100,NA,NA,NA)
value3 = c(100,12,234,500,600,400,345,345,100,150,234,354,600,700,500,325345,324,200)
df = data.frame(group1=group1, group2=group2, group3=group3, value1=value1, value2=value2, value3=value3)

group1_ = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
group2_ = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,3)
group3_ = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
value1_ = c(100,100,600,400,NA,100,150,150,700,500,NA,200)
value2_ = c(200,150,300,500,NA,NA,400,300,600,100,NA,NA)
value3_ = c(100,234,600,400,345,100,234,354,700,500,325345,200)
df_wanted = data.frame(group1=group1_, group2=group2_, group3=group3_, value1=value1_, value2=value2_, value3=value3_)

df %>%
    mutate(group3 = if_else(is.na(group3), 0, group3)) %>%
    group_by(group1, group2, group3) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~max(., na.rm = TRUE)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    na_if(-Inf) %>%
    group_by(group1, group2) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(c('value1', 'value2', 'value3')), funs('max'=max(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
    na_if(-Inf) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(c('value1', 'value2', 'value3')), funs(if_else(. > 0 & is.na(.), paste0(., '_max'), .)))
#> Error in df %>% mutate(group3 = if_else(is.na(group3), 0, group3)) %>% : could not find function "%>%"
```

df_wanted is expected dataframe, and I can solve it for 3 columns, but I really don't want to write hundreds of columns in order to solve this)

Comment: If there is a pattern for column names, for example, all starts with "value", you can use ```vars(starts_with("value"))```. See ```?vars/?select``` for more detail.

Comment: and I don't need '_max' columns, but I can do it by myself)

Comment: no, I just have list of columns, and there're absolutely no patterns

Answer (score 3):

Using the newer versions of `dplyr`, use `across` to loop over multiple columns.  Instead of base `max` use `collapse::fmax` which will return NA if all the values are NA.  Do the grouping, `summarise` across the 'value' columns, apply `fmax`.  In the second round, drop the 'group3' from grouping (`drop_last`  in `summarise`), `replace` the NA with the `fmax` of value columns.  Or instead of `replace`, also use `coalesce(.x, fmax(.x))`

```
library(dplyr)
library(collapse)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group1, group2, group3 = replace_na(group3, 0)) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), fmax), .groups = "drop_last") %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with('value'), ~ coalesce(.x, fmax(.x))))  %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 6
   group1 group2 group3 value1 value2 value3
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      1      1      0    100    200    100
 2      1      1      1    100    150    234
 3      1      2      0    600    300    600
 4      1      2      1    400    500    400
 5      1      3      0    100     NA    345
 6      1      3      1    100     NA    100
 7      2      1      0    150    400    234
 8      2      1      1    150    300    354
 9      2      2      0    700    600    700
10      2      2      1    500    100    500
11      2      3      0    200     NA 325345
12      2      3      1    200     NA    200
```

Comment: it's almost what I need, but I don't want to replace all values with max, only for NA's. So 4th value of 'value1' should be 400

Comment: @AlibekGaliyev It is a bit perplexing that someone removed your later comment that it worked and retained the original comment.